# Setting and getting fields depending on class

Tags: java, netbeans

Ive got 2 packages: Presentation, where main class is with a class Methods,
and a package with Entities: Entity1 and Entity2.
Entity1 has `private String entity1var;` and
Entity2 has `private Integer entity2var;`

Classes look like this:

```
public class Entity1 {
private String entity1var;

/**
 * @return the entity1var
 */
public String getEntity1String() {
    return entity1var;
}

/**
 * @param entity1String the entity1var to set
 */
public void setEntity1String(String entity1String) {
    this.entity1var = entity1String;
}
}
```

And:

```
public class Entity2 {
private Integer entity2var;

/**
 * @return the entity2var
 */
public Integer getEntity2Integer() {
    return entity2var;
}

/**
 * @param entity2Field the entity2var to set
 */
public void setEntity2Integer(Integer entity2Field) {
    this.entity2var = entity2Field;
}
}
```

The main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String ARGS[]){
    Methods _methods = new Methods();
    _methods.doSomething("Entity1");
    _methods.doSomething("Entity2");
}
}
```

Methods class:

```
public class Methods {
public void doSomething(String newClass){
    try {
        Class _class =  Class.forName("Entities."+newClass);
        //How can I set the variable on each class 
        //and get the value after 

        //Something similar to this:
        //_class.setEntity1String("Im new");
        //System.out.println(_class.getEntity1String); -> Result: Im new

        //_class.setEntity2Integer(777);
        //System.out.println(_class.getEntity2Integer); -> Result: 777


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Methods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,         ex);
    }
}
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
    Class newClass = Class.forName("Entities."+className);
    Method newMethod = newClass.getDeclaredMethod("getEntity1String");
    Object newValue = newMethod.invoke(newClass.newInstance());
    System.out.println(newValue);
```

It does show the value in the variable if I give it a value `private String entity1var = "Something new"` but how can I change tha value without using the classic instantiation ? I want to avoid this because I dont know the class Ill receive:

```
Entity1 entity = new Entity1();
entity.setEntity1String("Im also new");
```

SOLUTION (thanks to immibis):

```
        Class _class = Class.forName("Entities." + newClass);
        Object _classInstance = (Object) _class.newInstance();
        Method _newMethod = _class.getDeclaredMethod("setEntity1String", String.class);
        _newMethod.invoke(_classInstance, "New String");

        Method _method = _class.getDeclaredMethod("getEntity1String");
        Object _methodValue = _method.invoke(_classInstance);
        System.out.println(_methodValue);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (I'm asking because it doesn't make a lot of sense to do the thing you're trying to do, and there's probably a much easier way to do it)

Comment: @immibis ive got a lot of classes lets say: employee with fields: name, deptno, sal etc etc... another class called Superior with different fields than employee. I want to make (3 level architecture, focusing on DAO now), where you give a method its class name and it automatly inserts into the database all the fields the class has, if they were previously set. Something like you set all the fields of an Employee and then you want to insert it into the DB, i dont want to do individual methods for all entities.

Comment: @immibis I want to avoid: insertSuperior(), insertEmployee()... insertEtc()... where each individual methods has: Superior superior = new Superior(); then superior.getName ... superior.getSal ... then throw these variables into the database, ofc all this for the many classes i might have.

Comment: So you want to write your own ORM?

Comment: @immibis something like that, I want to make a method where you give it all the info necessary for the query, something like doThis("Select * from emp","all","Employee"); Where first parameter is the query, second the type: all, update, insert... And 3rd parameter the Entity to get the fields from.

Comment: Ok, well, have fun with that. As to your question: are you asking how to call a method using reflection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70984/discussion-between-alpha2k-and-immibis).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71049/discussion-between-alpha2k-and-immibis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `getEntity1String` using reflection like this:

```
Class newClass = Class.forName("Entities."+className);
Method newMethod = newClass.getDeclaredMethod("getEntity1String");
Object newValue = newMethod.invoke(theInstanceYouWantToCallTheMethodOn);
```

You can call `setEntity1String` using reflection, in the same way, like this:

```
Class newClass = Class.forName("Entities."+className);
Method newMethod = newClass.getDeclaredMethod("setEntity1String", String.class); // argument types need to be passed to getDeclaredMethod
newMethod.invoke(theInstanceYouWantToCallTheMethodOn, newValue); // need to pass the actual argument values now; also we don't care about the return value so it's not assigned to anything
```